# When should one of my four main characters die?

Tags: creative-writing, fiction, characters, fantasy

I'm writing a book series (I may or may not publish it, not sure) that I'd like to have as 5 books long. I have four main characters, and I want part of the story to be three of them dealing with the other's death. However, I can't figure out which book that character should die in. I'm thinking either books 3, 4, or 5, but is 3 too early? 5 too late? Should the character die at the end of the book? I'm also planning for the three remaining to meet someone else to "join their party," so should I do that in the same book, or the next?

Sorry if this seems like too many questions, but here's the gist:

When should one of my four main characters die in a 5-book series, and when should I introduce the new fourth main character?

Answer (score 1):

If the loss of that character proves to be very tragic for the rest, you might consider having him or her die before page one of book one. Then, the rest of the characters start off devastated and have to work through their grief before admitting another into their ranks. The story of the deceased character could be told via flashbacks, fond memories, stories told, etc.

Comment: this is a really good idea!! ill see if it works out